# Black screen when sizing JFrame/JPanel with Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()

Tags: java, graphics, swing

I am working on a game engine.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            
            Dimension size = new Dimension(800, 600);
//          Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("MRE");
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setSize(size);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setSize(size);
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            frame.add(panel);
        });
    }
}
```

When you run this code you should see an undecorated frame with a blue JPanel.
However if you switch the size variable with the commented one the whole screen turns black.
When I disabled `sun.java2d.opengl`it worked, but I want to draw all graphics using the GPU and not the CPU.
Debugging it, I noticed the issue is only when the size is the screen size (1280, 1024), The dimensions 1280, 1025 work fine

Comment: What values do you get back from Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()? Have you tried logging them to a console/log file or inspecting them in a debugger with a breakpoint?

Comment: @DMGregory `java.awt.Dimension[width=1280,height=1024]` I would like to know if the issue is for me only or it is a common issue

Comment: Why are you adding the JPanel *after* you've called `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame? Doing this means that the GUI has already been rendered when the panel is added. Better to call `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame after all components have been added.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels still didnt fix the issue :/